# c++ class errors does not name a type

Tags: c++, class

Trying to have a print function inside a class to print declared variables.

```
class MovieData{
private:
    int year, runtime;
    string title, director; 
public:
    MovieData(string t, string d, int y, int rt){
        year = y;
        runtime = rt;
        title = t;
        director = d;
    }

    print{
        cout << title << " (" << year << "). Directed by " << director << ". (" << rt << " minutes)";
    }
};
```

Error comes out to this:

```
main.cpp:20:9: error: ‘print’ does not name a type
     print{
     ^
main.cpp: In function ‘void doIt(std::string, std::string, int, int)’:
main.cpp:33:5: error: ‘class MovieData’ has no member named ‘print’
md.print();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need parentheses after `print` as well as a return type, like so: `void print() {...}`.

Comment: Thanks i'm in the process of the learn cPP this was my first ever class written in c++ i should have seen that it just slipped my mind for some reason. thanks :)